# Is it possible to preview a Slack Template built with the block kits in app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

We have been building a slack alerting feature made available to our users.

At the moment they have to format the template by themselves using the [slack block kit](https://api.slack.com/block-kit) and to test it they can send the message via our bot but as you can imagine it's very flooding.

We'd like to offer a preview feature in-app (react TS) rendering the template as they write it but it doesn't seem to exist within the slack api.

Anyone has crossed this issue without recoding slack' UI by any chance ?

Comment: Did y'all ever find a solution or API for this?